# Cannot read property 'data' of undefined inside promise. At a very strange place

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I don't know how to call it.

Two funcitons in my object:

```
login: (credentials) => {
    console.log('im in login user');

    axios.post('/api/auth/login', credentials)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data);
                return res.data;
            }).then(
            (toStore) => {
                this.store('hey'); // When I remove this, all OK
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                return false;
            })
},

store: (something) => {
    console.log('in user. store');
    // localStorage.setItem(this.storageKey, dataToStore);
},
```

But look at the `this.store('hey');` line. When I remove it, I can't see the error. When I have it, I have the error. But what `data` does the error mean?
[image: error]

Ok, I found the problem. `Error` doesn't have `response` property. And I getting the error because of... It was an object, not a class. As I converted the object to class, It's OK now.

Comment: Something goes wrong in `this.store(...)`, and the `error` object has no `.response` property. `console.log(error)` to see the error.

Comment: what is the second `.then()` for exactly? you're getting your response in the first `.then()` with you get back `res.data` so why not try doing the `this.store('hey')` in the first `.then()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error.response is undefined. That's why you're getting "Cannot read 'data' of undefined".

To protect yourself from this error, I would try the following code...

```
        .catch(error => {
                console.log( (error.response || {}).data );
                return false;
            })
```

However, the underline reason why you're not seeing the error when you remove this.store('hey') is a different problem. It seems to be a scope issue. Try removing "this."

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the [behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions) of `this` in arrow functions.

If you replace  `login: (credentials) => {}` with `login: function (credentials){}`, 
then `this.store('hey')` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thanks to everyone, I found all the errors in my code.
There was two of them:

1. `error.response` is not defined (There's no such property). Proper line should be 
   `console.log(error);`.
2. Also, because of arrow-functions behavior (scope issue), the login function couldn't see my `store` function.

In fact, I got error #2 in second `then` statement, so that led my program inside `catch` statement, where was error #1.